# RealityKit Materials: Basic Gradient

Tags: swiftui, metal, realitykit, metalkit, reality-composer-pro

---

Hello!

I’m trying to make a material in `RealityKit` that has a basic gradient. I am making an iPadOS app.

A few thoughts:

- I cannot use Reality Composer Pro to do this because the Shader Graph tool only works for visionOS.
- I cannot use a Metal file to create a shader because I am using a .swiftpm (app playgrounds) file targeted for Swift Playgrounds. Metal files don’t seem to work on Swift Playgrounds (it’s a *Swift* playground, after all).
- I would prefer to not use image textures for a simple thing like this. That would take up storage. I wish it was as easy as applying a `.basecolor` with a `UIColor`, but `UIColor` does not support gradients.

What are my options? I know my requirements are likely not typical, but I really need to try to not break those.

I looked into `CustomMaterial` from `RealityKit` but once again, those take Metal shaders. Amazing tool, but I sadly cannot use them because I’m using a Swift Playground that doesn’t seem to with Metal files, at least it seems.

I’ve briefly done research on MetalKit? Could that help me out?

Let’s say I have a simple box in `RealityKit`. How would I apply a simple gradient to it given my constraints?

I really appreciate the help.

P.S. This is a SwiftUI project for reference.

EDIT:

Could I create a texture without images, perhaps by making a view into a texture and applying it? How would I do this? What are the pros and cons of this?

Another thought was could I just use `MetalKit` to create the gradient and apply it using `CustomMaterial`?

Answer (score 1):

#### RealityKit gradient texture programmatically

You can definitely create a gradient fill for a RealityKit texture (without the help of the Metal Shading Language and raster files) if you use the `ImageRenderer` object that generates procedural images from SwiftUI views. This is what the code looks like:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct GradientView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 512, height: 512)
            .foregroundStyle(
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.yellow, .red]), 
                                              startPoint: .top, 
                                                endPoint: .bottom)
            )
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RealityKitView()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

```
struct RealityKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    
    @MainActor func textureFromView() -> UnlitMaterial {
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: GradientView())
        guard let cgImage = renderer.cgImage else { return .init() }
        
        var material = UnlitMaterial()
        material.color.texture = try! .init(.generate(from: cgImage, 
                                       options: .init(semantic: .color)))
        return material
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let box = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.5))
        box.orientation = simd_quatf(angle: .pi/4, axis: [1,1,0])
        box.model?.materials = [self.textureFromView()]
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        anchor.addChild(box)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```